# How to use SQL-View with PQGrid in combination of saving to db

Tags: php, mysql, view, grid

PQGrid: How I can save changes from grid to DB when I have a View as data source

I have read all examples from the homepage/forum etc. Furthermore I tried to transfer from jqGrid / other Gridtools to PQGrid. No chance.

The code below shows the PopUp-Editing opportunity and when I change any value, e.g. Prio = Priority, the values in the grid are edited, but when I reload the data, I got the original value from database.

Likewise I have created a PHP-file (Vormerkungen_Grid_Speichern.php) for parameter 'editurl' by a template, but nothing happens. He don't call this special file.

```php
<?php
    // FILENAME: Vormerkungen_Grid_Speichern.php
    // Datei dient nur zum Speichen von Veränderungen im Grid
    require ('./system_connector_mysql.php');

    $artikelnr = $_POST['ArtikelNr'];
    $aufgabe = $_POST['Aufgabe'];
    $prio = $_POST['Prio'];

    echo $_POST['ArtikelNr'];
    echo $_POST['Aufgabe'];
    echo $_POST['Prio'];

    switch ($_POST["oper"]) {
        case "add":
          // do mysql insert statement here
            break;

        case "edit":
                $query = "UPDATE tab_vormerkungen SET Aufgabe = '$aufgabe', Prio=$prio WHERE ArtikelNr=$artikelnr";
                mysql_query($query) OR ('Vormerkungen_Speichern.php - Zeile 13 |' . mysql_error());

                $datei = fopen('Vormerkungen_Speichern.txt', 'w');
                fwrite($datei, $query);
                fclose($datei);
            break;

            case "del":
          // do mysql delete statement here
            break;
    }

?>
```

```
    // FILENAME: Vormerkungen.php
      function editRow() {
          var rowIndx = getRowIndx();
          if (rowIndx != null) {

              var row = $grid.pqGrid('getRowData', { rowIndx: rowIndx });
              var aufgabeAlt = row.Aufgabe;

              var $frm = $("form#crud-form");
              $frm.find("input[name='artikelnr']").val(row.ArtikelNr);
              $frm.find("input[name='aufgabe']").val(row.Aufgabe);
              $frm.find("input[name='prio']").val(row.Prio);
              $frm.find("input[name='VFG']").val(row.VFG);

              $("#popup-dialog-crud").dialog({ title: "Vormerkung " + row.ArtikelNr + " bearbeiten", buttons: {
                  Update: function () {
                      //update row.
                      row = [];
                      row.ArtikelNr = $frm.find("input[name='artikelnr']").val();
                      row.Aufgabe = $frm.find("input[name='aufgabe']").val();
                      row.Prio = $frm.find("input[name='prio']").val();

                      // Umsetzung im Grid
                      $grid.pqGrid('updateRow', { rowIndx: rowIndx, row: row, checkEditable: false });

                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  Cancel: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }
              }).dialog("open");
          }
      }
```

Comment: I recommend you to try jqGrid for PHP where you do not need to add any code. Everything is do automatically. [Demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/demos/jqgrid/) Features [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102675)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tony Tmov (Sarcasm). PQGrid has a better license for me, that is the reason why I have choose PQGrid.

I think my biggest problem is the data source. If I didn't have a view as a data source, I wouldn't have a problem with storing it in the database.

But I also have no other choice with the data source.